# Integration of PortQry with ElectronJS Desktop App

Tags: javascript, tcp, udp, electron, port

I'm currently trying to use ElectronJS to build a wrapper around [Microsoft's PortQry CLI](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/310099/description-of-the-portqry-exe-command-line-utility) to automatically check for connectivity to my Company's services (Active Directory, Outlook etc.) and have a better looking GUI. (I like bootstrap)

The plan is for my electronJS app to run the CLI locally and get the output. I tried using [node-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd) but I can't get the output to show.

Below are my electronJS files:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p id="input">Hello World</p>
    </div>

<script src="./backend.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

backend.js

```
var cmd=require('node-cmd');

    cmd.get(
        'C:\PortQryV2\portqry -n google.com -p tcp -o 8080',
        function(err, data, stderr){
            document.getElementById("input").innerHTML=data;
        }
    );
```

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadFile('index.html')
  win.webContents.openDevTools()
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

So the PortQry is supposed to run, and change the p tag to display the output instead. But I can't get this to work. I was thinking of seeing if nodejs's child_process would work, but I can't seem to be able to import it into my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I realize how stupid this question is now.

Electronjs uses nodejs as runtime. I was previously launching index.html in chrome, hence it never worked. You have to launch the electron-app for it to work.